# How to select partition name on basics of data

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, database-administration

I want to select the partition name on basics of data.
below is the senior

p1 contains data for 1 Feb
p2 contains data for 2 Feb

Now I want to select partition name on basics of data 
like

```
select partition_name from table
where table_name='ABC'
and date ='01-feb-2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use USER/ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS view and HIGH_VALUE column but this approach has few pitfalls - HIGH_VALUE has LONG type, we should treat it in different way for list and range partitioning, it does not work for hash partitioning and we should recognise maxvalue and default pseudo-values. Another way is to use CBO advice:

```
SQL> create table t (x int) partition by range (x)
  2  (
  3  partition p0 values less than(1)
  4  , partition p1 values less than(2)
  5  , partition pd values less than (maxvalue))
  6  /

SQL> explain plan
  2  set statement_id = 'plan.t.0' for
  3  select * from t where x = 0
  4  /

SQL> select
  2            column_value    as PARTITIONS
  3    from       TABLE(
  4                    XmlSequence( extract(
  5                            DBMS_XPLAN.Build_Plan_Xml( 'PLAN_TABLE', 'plan.t.0' ),
  6                            '/plan/operation/partition'
  7                    )
  8                  )
  9            );

PARTITIONS                                                                      
----------------------------------------                                        
<partition start="1" stop="1"/>                                                 
<partition start="1" stop="1"/>                                                 

SQL> select partition_name from user_tab_partitions where table_name = 'T' and partition_position = 1
  2  /

PARTITION_NAME                                                                  
------------------------------                                                  
P0                                                                              

SQL> explain plan
  2  set statement_id = 'plan.t.1' for
  3  select * from t where x = 1
  4  /

SQL> select
  2            column_value    as PARTITIONS
  3    from       TABLE(
  4                    XmlSequence( extract(
  5                            DBMS_XPLAN.Build_Plan_Xml( 'PLAN_TABLE', 'plan.t.1' ),
  6                            '/plan/operation/partition'
  7                    )
  8                  )
  9            );

PARTITIONS                                                                      
----------------------------------------                                        
<partition start="2" stop="2"/>                                                 
<partition start="2" stop="2"/>                                                 

SQL> select partition_name from user_tab_partitions where table_name = 'T' and partition_position = 2;

PARTITION_NAME                                                                  
------------------------------                                                  
P1                                                                              

SQL> explain plan
  2  set statement_id = 'plan.t.3' for
  3  select * from t where x = 3
  4  /

SQL> select
  2            column_value    as PARTITIONS
  3    from       TABLE(
  4                    XmlSequence( extract(
  5                            DBMS_XPLAN.Build_Plan_Xml( 'PLAN_TABLE', 'plan.t.3' ),
  6                            '/plan/operation/partition'
  7                    )
  8                  )
  9            );

PARTITIONS                                                                      
----------------------------------------                                        
<partition start="3" stop="3"/>                                                 
<partition start="3" stop="3"/>                                                 

SQL> select partition_name from user_tab_partitions where table_name = 'T' and partition_position = 3;

PARTITION_NAME                                                                  
------------------------------                                                  
PD
```

Answer (score 0):

With a sensible partition naming convention, this is trivial.

You could also probably find a row for that value, and use DBMS_RowID to get the file and block that it is in, then read DBA_Extents to see get the physical object for the row -- that would give you the partition name.

That aside, there is an undocumented function TBL$OR$IDX$PART$NUM that gives this information.